# How to check every item in page if its belong to the user

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my application, I try to do a simple validation of the data before I return it to the user to check that the data really belongs to the user. For example, if the user uses GET /recipe/{id}, the application will check if the user's ID and recipe.getUser().getId() are the same or not.
Im using this solution when returning one object.

```
public Recipe getRecipe(Long id){
 //Returns current user
 User user = userService.currentUser();
 Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findById(id).get();
 
 //Check if Id is same or not
 if(recipe.getUser.getId() != user.getId()){
   log.error("Permission denied.");
   return null;
 }

 return recipe;
}
```

In what way can I similarly check all items in a page if they really belong to the user?

```
public Page<Recipe> getRecipeByPage(Long id, int pageNumber, int pageSize){
 Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);
 return recipe.findRecipeByUserId(id, pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Recipe> list = recipe.findRecipeByUserId(id, pageable).getContent();
```

You can get a list of items from the Page using the `getContent()` method. From there you can iterate the list or use streams to check if all Recipes have the required user id.